# #include <string> file not found in iOS in C++ file

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I have a objective c/c++ project under iOS, moving it from OS/X and I get a 'file not found' error on

```
#include <string>
```

It's a clean project, and I've just added the files from the old project. Are the STL includes set up in XCode? A find produces a number of possibilities e.g.

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/debug/
```

but adding this to the search path just threw up more errors. Any suggestions?
(apart from don't use string - it's in house code I'm porting)

xcode 4.2.1, ios5.0 running on OS/X 10.7.3 and it's in a .cpp file, the code works fine on OS/X

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Are you really sure `<string>` is included only from a .cpp file?

I just tested on a fresh project, by adding a .cpp file and including `<string>`, and it works, just as expected (same Xcode version, same SDK version).

But if I include `<string>` in a .m file, then of course I got a «file not found» compiler error.

So double-check this, as the error may come from here.

Do you include `<string>` from a .cpp file only, or from a .h file, intended to be used by a .cpp implementation?
Then maybe it's also included by a .m file, hence the error.

Also check your precompiled headers, if any, to see if you include some C++ stuff there...

Also remember, in that later case, that you can rely on the `__cplusplus` macro, when needed.

Comment: @MacMade - you were correct it was being #included from a .m file through a few includes - my bad - the error through me, along with my unfamiliarity with iOS - thanks

Comment: It's worth noting here that ALL headers that include the header with the offending `<string>`, as well as headers that include those headers (etc) will need their .m changed to .mm. There is a solution for this that I adhere to as much as possible. And that is to never include c-style headers in my obj-c header files. Instead, as much as possible, I include them only from the .mm files. That way, other headers "up the chain" will not be effected.

Answer (score 19):

If you include a header in an ObjC file and it includes `<string>` then you hit errors like this.  For all .m files XCode uses a C compiler (clang or llvm-gcc).  For all .mm files it will use (clang++ or llvm-g++).

I suggest going through and renaming all your .m files to .mm.  Including main.m to main.mm.

Comment: This worked for me when the included .h was several classes down form a .m so yes work up the tree changing the .m not just the one you including your .h and .cpp's

Comment: One thing to notice is that, you have to rename the files from .m to .mm inside xcode, so xcode knows to update the project settings associated with the .mm file. If you simply renamed the .m files on disk and did a search and replace in the .pbxproj (replace all occuriences of .m to .mm), it won't work because there are other properties of the file which are not updated. In this case, you will have to remove the references to these files in xcode and then drag and drop the affected .mm files back to your project.

Answer (score 1):

For me the reason was

MyHeader.h (which includes #include ) target was public. Changed it to project and it compiled.

For cocoa pod:
s.public_header_files = 'MyProject/Classes/**/*.h'

s.project_header_files = 'MyProject/Classes/MyHeader.h'