# Xcode: C++ error: unknown type name 'class' did you mean 'Class'

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode8

I'm trying to implement C++ class inside my Xcode project but I'm getting the following error:

```
Expected ';' after top level declarator
Unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'
```

[image]
This is what I'm doing. I'm adding new C++ file:

[image]
And I'm adding the header file:

[image]
After that I'm adding this to the header file:

```
#ifndef DoingSomething_hpp
#define DoingSomething_hpp
#include <stdio.h>
class DoingSomething {
public:
    static DoingSomething *instance();
    int doSomething();
};
#endif /* DoingSomething_hpp */
```

But the error start showing after I add the DoingSomething.hpp to my viewController:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DoingSomething.hpp"

@interface ViewController ()
```

Any of you knows why of this error or how can I fixed or if there is work around this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is your view controller an objective-c++ file?

Comment: @dan, my viewController is Objective-C file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10727702/7365866 `.m` files in XCode are compiled with a C compiler (clang or llvm-gcc) where as `.mm` files are compiled with clang++ or llvm-g++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you use C++ header in an Objective-C file (which is superset of C), that's why it doesn't recognize C++ syntax. To make it compile properly you should only include C++ headers in c++ or Objective-C++ (.mm) source files. Try changing the viewControllers file extension from .m to .mm

Answer (score 1):

Change the file extension from `.m` (Objective C) to `.mm` (Objective C++) and your compile will go much smoother.

Answer (score 0):

I had a mix of C and C++ files so I had to wrap the C++ header contents with "#ifdef __cplusplus" as per below. This was immediately inside the usual "#ifndef" for the header.

#ifdef __cplusplus

#include <whatever.h>

class Blah
{
...
}

#endif /* __cplusplus */

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks.